# how to change x axis in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to create a bar chart showing days of each month in a year. I want to change the numbers in x-axis of bar chart, but it turns out that the number starts from 0 and ends with 11, instead of 1 to 12. How can I solve this problem?

```
    //x 
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width - padding.left - padding.right]);

//y 
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,d3.max(dataset)])
    .range([height - padding.top - padding.bottom, 0]);

//the define of x
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

//define of y
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");


/add x
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","axis")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + padding.left + "," + (height - padding.bottom) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

[image]

Comment: Set a different domain for `xScale`.

Comment: I thought changing domain as well.. bur it moves the bar items too. Prefer to change labels with tickformat() on xaxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use tickformat() to format the axis labels as:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + 1; }); //make changes here relevant to ur data
```

Comment: Can I ask you another question? If I want to change the number of month into something like "January, February", how can I do it?

Comment: Create an array of months:
  var months = ["Jan","Feb"...
and
   .tickFormat(function(d) { return months[d]; });

Comment: Thank you! Your advice is really helpful!